# Facebook login - desperate

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, access-token

There may well be something glaringly obvious I'm missing here, but I've been trying for days to get a simple login with email, user_location and user_education_history scope.

I have the FB javascript in my first asp.net page with the login button.  On clicking that there is a redirect to my page FBLogin.aspx, where I get the cookie fbsr_appID, and from that I retrieve the signed request and from that the code string.

However I cannot proceed further.
I have had no luck with the c# facebook API, and when I try to get the access_token using

the url : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=2{appID}&redirect_uri={url}&client_secret={secret}&code={code}

then I get a JSON response with "Invalid verification code".

When I try the same URL in Facebook's object debugger, I get:
Missing Required Property   The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property   The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property   The og:title property is required

Why does there need to be a redirect_uri in there, and how does it work since I am using http://127.0.0.0:81/  (localhost)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou,

John.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to redirect you can just send in an empty string for redirect_uri.

Comment: I removed the redirect_url param and get the same results from the debugger.
When I put the new url into a browser I get:
"message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",

Comment: you can't remove it but you should send https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=2{appID}&redirect_uri=&client_secret={secret}&code={code}